# How do I "clear" std::promise?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a program, which should in cycle launch 8 threads, which will return a value using `std::promise`. So I think I need to create a vector of 8 `promise` objects, get their `future`s, and use these `promise`s to return the values and then `join` the threads with `main`. The problem is this: on the next iteration I will create 8 more threads -- can i reuse the same `promise` objects, or do I need to create 8 more? I haven't found any way to reuse them on the internet, but maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: just clear the vector and create new ones.. seriously..

Comment: @DavidHaim, what is it with everyone adding their answers as comments instead of answers?

Comment: because I ahve nothing smarter to say other than that

Answer (score 26):

To reuse promises, simply reassign them.

```
std::promise<int> my_promise;
//use the promise
my_promise = std::promise<int>(); //now you have a new promise
```

Comment: it should be `my_promise = std::promise<int>()` not `my_promise = std::my_promise<int>()`. Isn't it ?

Comment: You can also do `std::promise<int>().swap(my_promise)`

Comment: @user0000001 although it might actually be clearer to write `my_promise = std::promise<int>()`

Comment: make that `my_promise = {};`

Answer (score 3):

std::promise is meant to be used only once, so I would suggest to either create this set of promises every time, or use other mechanisms to communicate between threads (like vector + mutex).
You could also consider using std::async instead of creating threads.

Comment: I don't see any issues in reusing an `std::promise`. After all, it supports `std::swap`. Though, in OP's use case it would probably be easier to create a new set of promises.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler to do this. You won't have to touch the line if you later decide to change the value type.

```
my_promise = {};
```